# How to use condition in sort function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I attempted to use condition to sort array by different fields:

```
 return source.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.orderBy && b.orderBy) {
        return sortOrder === 'asc'
          ? a.orderBy - b.orderBy
          : b.orderBy - a.orderBy;
      }
      
      return sortOrder === 'asc' ? a.name - b.name : b.name - a.name;
      
    });
```

I have got the error:

```
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

What is problem?

It works for me, but probably it could be better:

```
  return source.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.orderBy && b.orderBy) {
        return sortOrder === 'asc'
          ? a.orderBy - b.orderBy
          : b.orderBy - a.orderBy;
      }

      if (sortOrder === 'asc') {
        if (a.name < b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      } else {
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.name < b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
      }
    });
```

Comment: What are the types of `orderBy`? You're trying to do subtraction with them, so they have to be one of the types listed in the error.

Comment: `orderBy` it is number type. `name` is string

Comment: So, as you say, `name` is a `string` -- you're trying to do subtraction with it. That doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, how then? > < else?

Comment: You can use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to compare strings. -> `return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now you haven't defined `source`, so I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I already added into question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot substract strings.
You should use `a.prototype.localeCompare(b)`

It will return `1` if a > b; `-1` if b > a; and otherwise `0`

In your example you should do following:

```
return source.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.orderBy && b.orderBy) {
    return sortOrder === "asc" ? a.orderBy - b.orderBy : b.orderBy - a.orderBy;
  }

  return sortOrder === "asc" ? a.localeCompare(b) : b.localeCompare(a);
});
```